# How to configure latest 32-bit emacs & AUCTeX in Windows 7?

Tags: auctex, microsoft-windows, preview-latex

I'm on Windows 7, 32-bit processor and I'm trying to set up emacs and AUCTeX with RefTeX. I've followed [Joachim Schlosser's english guide](http://www.latexbuch.de/install-latex-windows-7/#x1-140003.4) and [Youtube tutorial](http://www.latexbuch.de/installieren/emacs-latex-windows-7-video/) in German (even if I don't understand German).

When I open a `*.tex` file, there are no **Preview** or **LaTeX** menus, instead a spartan **TeX** menu that doesn't offer the possibility to customize AUCTeX. Can someone please help me get AUCTeX to work the *preview-latex* feature that is supposed to display math expressions inside the buffer and not in a separate pdf program such as SumatraPDF? I've also downloaded the appropriate png.dll and zlib.dll (see guide above).

[image: where's the LaTeX menu? Or preview-latex sub-menu?]

I'm starting to doubt whether I got the right versions of emacs and AUCTeX for my OS. I've got `emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip` and `auctex-11.88-e24.4-msw.zip`, are these the correct zip files?

This is my `.emacs` file which I have created by copy-pasting blocks of code from different places in the net, since I don't know *elisp*.

```
(server-start)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")

;;; AUCTeX
;; Customary Customization, p. 1 and 16 in the manual, and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc2
(setq TeX-parse-self t); Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t); Enable parse on save.
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

(setq TeX-PDF-mode t); PDF mode (rather than DVI-mode)

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode); Enable Flyspell mode for TeX modes such as AUCTeX. Highlights all misspelled words.
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode); Enable Flyspell program mode for emacs lisp mode, which highlights all misspelled words in comments and strings.
(setq ispell-dictionary "english"); Default dictionary. To change do M-x ispell-change-dictionary RET.
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (TeX-fold-mode 1))); Automatically activate TeX-fold-mode.
(setq LaTeX-babel-hyphen nil); Disable language-specific hyphen insertion.

;; " expands into csquotes macros (for this to work babel must be loaded after csquotes).
(setq LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}"
      LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{")

;; LaTeX-math-mode http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/auctex/Mathematics.html
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
```

Comment: Well, configuration looks ok, but I'd say you don't have AUCTeX at all.  Are you sure you installed it?  By far, the easiest way to install AUCTeX is through elpa: `M-x package-install RET auctex RET`, restart Emacs just to be sure and you're done.

Comment: Your question title does not match the actual question. Please change the title to reflect the fact that you are asking about installing AucTex or getting it to work.

Comment: @giordano I've tried that a few days ago but somehow couldn't get `preview-latex` to work. That's why I read and followed Mr. Schlosser's guide. He says to download AUCTeX zip file, copy it's content into `emacs-24.4` folder under `C:\Program Files\ ` overwriting at least one file/folder. I just did step-by-step what he did in his youtube tutorial. What can I do now? Can I still do `M-x package-install` or will it affect some internal files?

Comment: No, if possible I'd suggest you to uninstall that Emacs and install a fresh one and the install AUCTeX with Elpa.  In this way you'll also updates to the package as soon as they are available.  Installation described in that tutorial is pretty outdated nowadays and I don't think upgrading AUCTeX would be easy in that case (but I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure).

Comment: @giordano Can you please specify which version of emacs for Windows I should download and install in my 32-bit system, on my laptop computer? I'm really confused. Which of the following is it? **(a)**  `emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip` **(b)** `emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip` **(c)** `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip ` [link to emacs ftp](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/)

Comment: They are just different versions of Emacs.  If you want the latest one (suggested) download **(a)** [`emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip`](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip).

Comment: Last I checked, the stock build of Emacs for Windows does not ship with the required *.dll files to view .png images -- those are used to create the preview the OP is interested in.  There are numerous threads dealing with how to view .png images in Emacs and links to Emacs for Windows distributions that come with the *.dll files needed to view those images.  There are even distributions that have AUCTeX already installed.  The OP may also need Ghostscript.  http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/

Comment: @lawlist Are the two dll files I've written above, ok to preview latex fragments in an *.org file too? Or is some other software required for previewing LaTeX fragments?

Comment: You can test to see whether .png images are supported by evaluating `(image-type-available-p 'png)` -- and you can see what .dll files are supported by checking the value of the variable `image-library-alist`

Answer (score 3):

I followed @giordano's advice and made a clean install of `emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip`. I basically still followed Schlosser's youtube tutorial, including the bit where he edits and installs the `*.reg` file. This time, however, I got the `libpng16-16.dll` and `zlib1.dll` files from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/filesa) and I did NOT extract the AUCTeX zip file's content into emacs' path. I installed AUCTeX from *within* emacs with `M-x package-install RET auctex RET`. My `.emacs` file is basically still the one above.

Once I got everything ready (I already had a working TeXLive distribution, by the way), I tried compiling a `test.tex` file with AUCTeX. At first I was still getting an error msg "preview imgage not available" but I had mistaken some code. After a few tries I got things right. The **Preview** and **LaTeX** menus are there, and I can see math preview *inside the buffer*! See picture below.

[image]

Comment: Please note Local variables must be at the end of the file.  When you open a file you just have to write where point is, above local variables.